Tooltip to display a respective background color specifically for the application, while still showing the vulnerabilities and duration normally
this.options.plugins = {
  tooltip: {
    callbacks: {
      // Suppress the default title (duration) rendering
      title: () => {
        return "";
      },
      // Suppress individual label rendering
      label: () => {
        return "";
      },
      // Combine everything in the afterBody
      afterBody: (context: any) => {
        console.log("context", context);
        const apps = context
          .map((item) => item.dataset.label)
          .join(", ");
        const duration = context[0].label;
        const vulns = context[0].raw;
        return [
          `application: ${apps}`,
          `vulnerabilities: ${vulns}`,
          `Duration: ${duration}`,
        ];
      },
    },
  },
};

I want the chart tooltip to display the application, vulnerabilities, and duration. However, for the application name in the tooltip, I would like it to have a background color.
current behaviour for only applications:

Expected behaviour for only applications i want like below colors for:

